# No Padlock for some subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, http, ssl, https

- I have successfully setup ssl
- The redirecting from http to https  is successful as well

But in my site, some webpages have the padlock and some dont
Although every page is redirected to https from http, some pages are still not secure. What can be the reason?

This is the result from **WhyNotPadlock**
https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/895057dd-2a4a-480a-b8a7-4bc6f9371bca

Can the reason be that im using TLS version 1?
If yes, can somebody please tell me how to upgrade it to 1.2 or 1.3. Im using AWS EC2 Linux for hosting

If that's not the reason, what is it and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with TLS or SSL Certiicate. I had links to http sites in those subdomains which was the reason for no Padlock. Sorry